# Defining global inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables, global

Is it possible to define a global variable inside a function? like this:

```
def posities():
    global blauw
    blauw = {"bl1":[0], "bl2":[0],"bl3":[0],"bl4":[0]}
    global geel
    geel = {"ge1":[0], "ge2":[0],"ge3":[0],"ge4":[0]}
    global groen
    groen = {"gr1":[0], "gr2":[0],"gr3":[0],"gr4":[0]}
    global rood
    rood = {"ro1":[0], "ro2":[0],"ro3":[0],"ro4":[0]}
    global ingenomenPos
    ingenomenPos = []
```

Or MUST I first declare to the variables outside of the function? Because when I define them inside the function and I try to acces them from another function, it doesn't recognise it. So I want to declare global variables without first declaring them outside the function.

So I try to acces those globals with this method:

```
def bezet():
    print (str(ingenomenPos))
```

which results in the error:

```
NameError: name 'ingenomenPos' is not defined
```

Comment: That's fine, but I do have a suggestion:  Instead of putting all of your `global` declarations just above each definition, you can do them all at the top like this: `global blauw, geel, groen, rood, ingenomenPos`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `global` statements only in functions, *nowhere else* (it has no effect elsewhere). Yes, it'll work, no you don't need to create the global outside first.

This is easily tested in the interpreter:

```
>>> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
>>> def bar():
...     global foo
...     foo = 'baz'
...
>>> bar()
>>> foo
'baz'
```

The `global` statement tells the Python compiler that assigning to the name should set a global, not a local variable. Without the statement, all use of a variable in a function becomes local as soon as it is used to bind to.

Note that you have to *call* the function; just the `global` statement being present in the function is not enough to bind the name. Python doesn't have 'declarations', names only exist through binding actions. See [*Naming and binding*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

If you still see the exception, then the assignment never was executed. Either you haven't called the function, or the `name = value` statement was never reached (because the function returned before that line or an exception was raised).

Comment: That's weird, I keep getting the error: NameError: name 'ingenomenPos' is not defined

Comment: @Nerotix: how are you calling the function? Your code, as posted (and the indentation corrected) works just fine.

Comment: "You can use global nowhere else" <- Can you explain this part? When I open up the interpreter I can put in `global x` without problems. P.S.: not my downvote.

Comment: @timgeb: sure, but it has no meaning. It only has meaning in a function.

Comment: Lol dude, I can't believe I made this mistake..... Damn school confusing me.. letting me make dicts inside a function for no reason -_- I forgot to initialise the function like u said so it wasn't even created yet. Thanks for the answer, I'm stupid and so is my school.